# lftp: removes folder prefix while uploading files

Tags: lftp

I want to upload some files in a local folder to a remote folder thanks to the command line's ftp client [lftp](http://lftp.tech/).

#### What I want :

In my local computer, I do have :

```
me@local $ tree
my-site
├── index.html
└── css/
```

When I go to my FTP server, I want to have :

```
me@ftp_server $ tree
dev-site/
├── index.html
└── css/
```

What I want to do is to upload the local **content** of the `my-site` dir to the remote `dev-site` dir; but not the `my-site` dir itself. So I just want to upload files and remove this directory prefix name.

#### What I tried :

I tried this :

```
# On my local computer :
$ ls
my-site/
$ lftp -u username,passwd ftp.foobar.cmo -e "mirror -R -p my-site/ dev-site/ ; quit"
```

Sadly, it uploads to local `my-site` dir into the remote `dev-site`, like :

```
# On my remote ftp server :
$ tree
dev-site/
└── my-site/
    ├── index.html
    └── css/
```

#### Workaround :

It works as excpected if I do :

```
# On my local computer :
$ cd my-site/
$ lftp -u username,passwd ftp.foobar.cmo -e "mirror -R -p ./ dev-site/ ; quit"
```

But I want to avoid this dirty `cd`.

#### Question:

Is there any way to remove a directory prefix while uploading files, in order to upload the content of a directory and not the directory itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That about if you do the mirror without the last trailing slash at the destination ftp dir?

`lftp -u user,password -e 'mirror -R -p /home/user/my-site dev-site ; quit' ftp.foo.cmo`

Works here using lftp version 3.7.3:

```
adminnicolas@fw1:~$ lftp --version
LFTP | Version 3.7.3 | Copyright (c) 1996-2008 Alexander V. Lukyanov
```

Comment: Removing the trailing slash on the destination dir did the trick :) thanks @nwildner